# How to call a method after old component removed from DOM when navigating in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm trying to run a method (on ComponentB) after a routerLink is clicked which navigates from ComponentA to ComponentB. It is important that this method is fired once navigation is fully complete (i.e. ComponentA has been destroyed + removed from DOM).

I've tried firing this in both `ngOnInit()`, `ngAfterViewInit()` of ComponentB, as well as subscribing to the router NavigationEnd:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.doSomething();
            }
        });
```

However all of these fire *before* ComponentA is removed from the DOM. If I place a breakpoint in `doSomething()` ComponentA is still visible in the DOM when it is fired. As far as I can tell, the call currently happens between ngOnDestroy() being called on ComponentA  and it actually being destroyed/removed from the DOM.

What seems to happen:

```
routerLink clicked
ComponentB created
NavigationEnd event fired
ComponentA ngOnDestroy()
ComponentB ngOnInit()
ComponentB ngAfterViewInit()
ComponentA destroyed (removed from DOM)
```

What I need:

```
routerLink clicked
ComponentB created
ComponentA destroyed (removed from DOM)
ComponentB doSomething()
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `RouterOutlet` directive exposes a [`deactivateEvents` @Output property](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L69):

```js
@Output('deactivate') deactivateEvents = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

and this emits when the current route is deactivated(which also involves that the component is destroyed at this point):

```js
deactivate(): void {
  if (this.activated) {
    const c = this.component;
    this.activated.destroy();
    this.activated = null;
    this._activatedRoute = null;
    this.deactivateEvents.emit(c);
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```html
<router-link (deactivate)="onDeactivate($event)"></router-link>
```

and now, depending on your current scenario, you could use a service to inform `ComponentB`.